# how to find the index of the maximum element of an integer array with null elements in it?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, indexing

I have an `ArrayList` say:

```
List<Integer> intlist= Arrays.asList(11,34,500,null,81, null);
```

I want to get the index of the maximum. But I have null elements in it. How?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `Stream` to filter out the null values, and find the max value. If a max is found, you can use the `indexOf` method to find the index of this item in your list.

**Code**

```
List<Integer> intlist = Arrays.asList(11, 34, 500, null, 81, null);

int maxindex = intlist.stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .max(Integer::compare)
            .map(intlist::indexOf)
            .orElse(-1);

System.out.println(maxindex);
```

**Result**:

```
2
```

### Alternative without finding the max + using index of

It's also possible to avoid the use of `indexOf` and directly get the max index by using a `reduce` method to compare all elements and keep the largest one. Here we create a stream to generate all possible indexes, and use those to check if the value is not null. After this check we reduce the stream to only preserve the index of the max value

```
int maxindex = IntStream.range(0, intlist.size())
            .filter(i -> intlist.get(i) != null)
            .reduce((i, j) -> intlist.get(i) > intlist.get(j) ? i : j)
            .orElse(-1);

System.out.println(maxindex);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Stream API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams.html) to find the maximum value which you can pass to [`List#indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-) to get its index.  Make sure to pass `Objects::nonNull` to [`Stream#filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) to discard `null` elements.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(11, 34, 500, null, 81, null);
        int idxMax = intList.indexOf(intList.stream()
                                            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                            .max(Integer::compare)
                                            .orElse(-1) // You can put here any value just to avoid NoSuchElementException 
                                                        // in case intList is empty. For empty intList, intlist.indexOf(that_value)
                                                        // will return -1 because that_value doesn't exist in the empty intList
                                    );
        System.out.println(idxMax);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2
```

Alternatively,

```
List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(11, 34, 500, null, 81, null);
int idxMax = intList.indexOf(intList.stream()
                                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                    .reduce(Integer::max)
                                    .orElse(-1)
                            );
System.out.println(idxMax);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check for `null` elements to ignore them in the loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getIndexOfMax(Arrays.asList(11,34,500,null,81, null))); //2
    System.out.println(getIndexOfMax(Arrays.asList(null,null,null,200))); //3
    System.out.println(getIndexOfMax(Arrays.asList(null,null,null))); //-1
}
private static int getIndexOfMax(List<Integer> list) {
    int indexOfMax = -1;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        Integer num = list.get(i);
        if(num != null && num > max) {
            indexOfMax = i;
            max = num;
        }
    }
    return indexOfMax;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but how do I get the original index of the max element ?

Comment: I misread the question, basically what you need to do is iterate over the list items, in each iteration check if ``num`` is not ``null`` and is greater than ``max`` (set to first index at the beginning), update the last to ``i``.

Comment: it fails when the input list is (null, null, null, 200)

Comment: @sank I updated the answer to handle this case

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I had misread the question.  I would recommend creating a method and returning -1 if no max was found.

```
List<Integer> intlist= Arrays.asList(11,34,500,null,81, null);
int index = getIndexForMax(intlist);
if (index >= 0) {
     System.out.println(intlist.get(index));
}
```

prints

```
500
```

The method.

```
public static int getIndexForMax(List<Integer> list) {
   int indx = -1; // default index
   int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // smallest possible value
   for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
      if (list.get(i) != null) {
        int cv = list.get(i); 
          if (cv > max) {
            max = cv;  // save max
            indx = i; // and its index
          }
      }
   }
   return indx;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but how do I get the original index of the max element?

Answer (score 1):

try below code

```
public static Integer max(List<Integer> intList) {
    if (intList == null || intList.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number list must not empty !");
    }
    Integer max = intList.get(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < intList.size(); i++) {
        if (max != null && intList.get(i) != null && max < intList.get(i)) {
            max = intList.get(i);
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```